# convert program from x86 to x64

Tags: c++

my boss ask me to pass one program to x64, but when I compile i get this error:
mm3dnow.h(19): fatal error C1189: #error:  This header is specific to X86 targets

I am very new in c++ and I don't know exactly what to change, I only want the program to work :,(
and this is the header:

```
#pragma once


#if !defined(_M_IX86)
#error This header is specific to X86 targets
#endif

#ifndef _MM3DNOW_H_INCLUDED
#define _MM3DNOW_H_INCLUDED
#ifndef __midl



#if !defined _M_IX86
    #error This header is specific to the X86 target
#endif


#include <vcruntime.h>
#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>


#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C" { /* Intrinsics use C name-mangling.  */
#endif  /* defined __cplusplus */

/* 3DNOW intrinsics */

void _m_femms(void);
__m64 _m_pavgusb(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pf2id(__m64);
__m64 _m_pfacc(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfadd(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfcmpeq(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfcmpge(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfcmpgt(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfmax(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfmin(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfmul(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfrcp(__m64);
__m64 _m_pfrcpit1(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfrcpit2(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfrsqrt(__m64);
__m64 _m_pfrsqit1(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfsub(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfsubr(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pi2fd(__m64);
__m64 _m_pmulhrw(__m64, __m64);
void _m_prefetch(void*);
void _m_prefetchw(volatile const void*_Source);

__m64 _m_from_float(float);
float _m_to_float(__m64);

/* Athlon DSP intrinsics */

__m64 _m_pf2iw(__m64);
__m64 _m_pfnacc(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pfpnacc(__m64, __m64);
__m64 _m_pi2fw(__m64);
__m64 _m_pswapd(__m64);

#if defined __cplusplus
}; /* End "C" */
#endif  /* defined __cplusplus */
#endif  /* __midl */
#endif  /* _MM3DNOW_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: Remove the `#error`? ;-)

Comment: @MarcGlisse this is probably a system header. Antonio we need to see the code that includes this header

Comment: Are you sure you still need 3DNow! support? AMD implemented the 3DNow! instruction set in their processors from 1998 through 2011. However, with the advent of the various SSE instruction sets, which AMD also implemented, 3DNow! already lost relevance years before it was discontinued.

Comment: Basically 3Dnow is deprecated, you need to use SSE instructions instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow!

Comment: It's possible, but not guaranteed, that the header is so old, the code was written before amd64/x64 was a thing and just assumed everyone had a 32-bit processor. You can tell by the `3DNOW` reference in the code - that's stuff from the late 90's. I don't think any modern processor supports 3DNOW from AMD or Intel.  So removing the `#errror` pragma might work. But the better approach would be to try and remove the header file from being referenced and fix whatever code was dependent on that header.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise your question is liable to be closed.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"

#include "lib\signal.h"
#include "libsom\som.h"
#include "libsom\node.h"
#include "KM\kmpp.c "

Comment: okey thanks, I am going to search with this information

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says that mm3dnow.h only works on x86. So for x64 you cannot use mm3dnow.h.

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply do not include any header files that are X86 specific (this includes recursive inclusion by other headers). If the code you want to port calls any methods declared in such files, you must dig deeper and replace them with appropriate functions that come with X64.

As you failed to provie any more details, I cannot give a more detailed answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: thank you for the comment, sorry I am learning how to use the platform, and I wasn't sure were to post it. These are the headers of the main ccp: #include "stdafx.h"

#include "lib\signal.h"
#include "libsom\som.h"
#include "libsom\node.h"
#include "KM\kmpp.c "